# Proper use of ARIA heading role

Tags: accessibility, usability, wai-aria

I wonder if anyone knows if the aria [role=heading](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#heading) can be used for non-text elements (such as images) as well?

For example:

```html
<img alt="..." role="heading" aria-level="1">
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use...

```
<h1><img alt="..."></h1>
```

...instead? This would seem to have the same functionality, but avoids the issue of whether ARIA is even supported.

This would also be search-engine (SEO) friendly, in that a web crawler will know that the contents of the  is being used as a heading and will treat it accordingly, while it is very unlikely to look at the aria attributes.

Comment: I think it would be because a header isn't alway the same as the heading. For example, the header would include the heading but also the subtitle, the date info, the author info etc. Also, you don't need to worry about whether ARIA is supported or not, it's just an attribute so it's not going to break anything through inclusion.

Comment: The question here is about headings, not header sections, so I'm not sure how your comment applies or changes this. It's reasonably clear from the [ARIA spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#heading) that the ARIA heading role maps to the Hn elements, not to larger header/footer sections.

Comment: Using the OP's code means you are *relying* on the user having a recent enough version of browser+screenreader in order for it to work; whereas screenreader support for Hn elements is very well established.  Use of Hn is also the correct HTML way of indicating an element is a header and is widely understood by screenreaders, indexers and others. ARIA roles are really a fallback mechanism for when you can't express the underlying meaning correctly in regular semantic HTML. I'd advise use of the OP's technique only if there was some compelling reason why they couldn't use Hn there.

Comment: Yes, using the OP's code would need a recent enough version, but since they're asking how best to use it, then I'd suggest not to use that code. That doesn't, however, mean that the heading role maps to the header element. See http://oaa-accessibility.org/example/15/ as an examples, and I disagree with your reading of the ARIA spec anyway, it quite clearly descends from sectionhead - "A structure that labels or summarizes the topic of its related section." That can include several elements, one of which may be a header element. I'd suggest the OP use both the role and a header.